# How to use C# webbrowser to select from dropdown selections and then invoke a form submit script

Tags: javascript, c#, html, forms, webbrowser-control

In a C# winform project I am using a webbrowser object to log into a website, navigate to a particular list and then work with that list. After logging in I need to select from some dropdown selection choices that are inside a form and then submit the form (there is no submit element - submitting the form is done by clicking on an image anchored with an onclick event, all as shown below.

Here's an abbreviated version of the code at the target site (I've shortened it quite a bit - i think I left everything pertinent in. I've also cut out all the styles to focus on the HTML and javascript). One final note - I looked for but did not find a function `objForm.submit`:

```
<form name="frm1" id="frm1" action="/tab/formaction.asp" method="post">
<table>
<tr><td> Locations</td></tr>
<tr><td>
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>Origin</td>
        <td>
            <select title="Choose Origin Location(s)" name="origin_location"
             id="origin_location" multiple="multiple">
                <option value="0">ANYWHERE</option>
        <option value="1">North West</option>
        <option value="2">North Central</option>
        <option value="3">Great Lakes</option>
        <option value="4">North East</option>
        <option value="5">South West</option>
    </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Destination</td>
        <td>
            <select title="Choose Destination Location(s)"
              name="destination_location" id="destination_location"
               multiple="multiple">
                <option value="0">ANYWHERE</option>
        <option value="1">North West</option>
        <option value="2">North Central</option>
        <option value="3">Great Lakes</option>
        <option value="4">North East</option>
        <option value="5">South West</option>
    </select>
        </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>Number of People</td>
        <td>
            <select name="people">
        <option value="1">1+</option>
                    <option value="2">2+</option>
                    <option value="3">3+</option>
                    <option value="4">4+</option>
            </select>
            <select style="visibility:hidden;" name="equality">
                <!--
                <option value="<=">Less than or Equal</option>
                <option value="=">Equal</option>
                !-->
                <option value=">=">Greater than or Equal</option>
            </select>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <a href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="objForm.submit(); return
                 false;">
                <img src="/tab/images/buttons/submit.gif" border="0"
                    WIDTH="71" HEIGHT="21">
            </a>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
</td></tr></table>
<input type="hidden" name="origin_text" id="origin_text">
<input type="hidden" name="origin_region_id" id="origin_region_id">
<input type="hidden" name="origin_state_id" id="origin_state_id">
<input type="hidden" name="origin_city_id" id="origin_city_id">

<input type="hidden" name="destination_text" id="destination_text">
<input type="hidden" name="destination_region_id"
      id="destination_region_id">
<input type="hidden" name="destination_state_id" id="destination_state_id">
<input type="hidden" name="destination_city_id" id="destination_city_id">

<input type="hidden" name="equality_text" id="equality_text">
<input type="hidden" name="sZip" id="sZip">
</form>
```

What I have tried:

My first thought was to set attributes for the first and second of the three things I want to choose, like this:

```
 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("origin_location")
   .SetAttribute("value", "4");

 webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("destination_location")
    .SetAttribute("value", "4");
```

I am not sure that I am doing those 2 correctly, and for the third, there is no ID, so I have no idea how to select it.

Finally, I want to click the anchored image or to invoke the onclick script in the cell that reads:

```
<a href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="objForm.submit(); return false;">
    <img src="/tab/images/buttons/submit.gif" border="0" WIDTH="71"
     HEIGHT="21">
</a>
```

As might be obvious, I am a fairly new coder and appreciate any help or guidance.

Comment: "I looked for but did not find a function `objForm.submit`" -- that is the JavaScript function your code is attempting to call when your form gets submitted. If it doesn't exist, you have to **create** it. Also, it will never get called successfully due to you returning false after it. `<a href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="objForm.submit(); return
                 false;">` should simply be `<a href="javascript: void 0;" onclick="objForm.submit();">` :)

Comment: Thanks. I didn't write the website - i just pasted what is there in the page source code. I am trying to create a program that logs in and scrapes a list that I work from. The form I am trying to submit defines the query that creates the list.
Also - a correction - the source does include a statement that:
        objForm.onSubmit = _customOnSubmit;
And there is a _customOnSubmit function.  I can paste that info if it helps - my thought about invoking the function is to simply do something like this:
     webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("objForm.submit");

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your right, u cant access to the third with the getElementbyID Methode, but it is possible to get this HTML Element with this:

```
webBrowser1.Document.getElementsByTagName("select");
```

This should return a HtmlElementCollection. Because there are only three "select" elements, it have to be the third in this collection.

To perform the Click u use the same getElementbyTagName Methode, but with an "a". If you have the right Element u perform the click with:

```
elementname.InvokeMember("click");
```

Tipp: Set a Breakpoint where the Collections are created and start in the Debug Mode. Than look if the elements are collected successfuly :)

Comment: HansKrywaa - your comment helped enormously.  Now I am onto the next step which is binding info in a table to a dataviewgrid - and of course I am struggling again with the fact that the site I am getting the info from rarely uses id's or even distinct classes.  I may be posting another question shortly....

Comment: I'm not sure how stars work - it looks like I don't have a high enough score or reputation here to give one - I don't see any link for stars.  but i did mark your answer with a checkmark as the best answer.  Hope that helps move you up.